# Task.Start() does not return until completed (Big Updated)

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, task, backgroundworker

I have a WinForms C# application (Web Crawler) which connects to a WCF self hosted Service, which in turn connects to an MS SQL Database.

**The WebCrawler** Starts (logs the user in etc) `LoginActual();`
Receives a URL to process and
starts a `BackGroundWorker` which actually starts the Crawler `RunCrawler();`

**RunCrawler()** gets the HTML from the URL to process and gets all the URLs within the html. The Urls are added to `alOutUrls`, which is an `ArrayList`. The URLs are then sent to `SendURls`(); If the URL being Processed returned an Error such as 404 then `SendError`(); is called.

If `alOutUrls` has more than 100 urls in it then it adds the URLs to a Queue for processing in a Task. And starts the `RunQueue` method as a new task.
Else
It iterates through alOutUrls in a foreach sending the Raptor Service API (RAPI) the URL and additional information.

**RunQueue()** Iterates through the `Queue` in a `While` statement sending the Raptor Service API (RAPI) the URL taken from the Queue and other additional information.

However, The following problems occur *all the time!*

1. Time Outs on the Send from the Client to the Service Host
2. The `RunQueue`() method does not seem to run in the background but blocks the application until it is completed; which defeats the problem.

**HUGE UPDATE**
A massive simplification of the code is here - which still has the same problems.

```
 private ArrayList alOutUrls = new ArrayList();
        private void RunCrawler()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                int ErrorCode = 0;
                string cu = alUrls[0].ToString();
                string html = LoadUrlIfNotContentType(cu, out ErrorCode);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
                {
                    alOutUrls = GetUrls(html, cu);
                    SendUrls(cu, ErrorCode); // Send the URLS
                }
                else
                    SendError(cu, ErrorCode); // Send the StatusCode of the Url 404, 500 etc 

                alUrls.RemoveAt(0);
                alUrls.AddRange(RAPI.SendUrls());
            }
        }

        private Task tRunQueue = null;
        private Queue<string> bigqueue = new Queue<string>();
        private bool IsContentObject = false;
        private void SendUrls(string cu, int ErrorCode)
        {
            foreach (string u in alOutUrls)
            {
                bigqueue.Enqueue(u);
            }

            if(tRunQueue == null)
            {
                tRunQueue = new Task(() => RunQueue(cu, IsContentObject, ErrorCode));               
                tRunQueue.Start();
            }
        }

        private void RunQueue(string cu, bool IsContentObject, int ErrorCode)
        {
            while (bgwCrawler.CancellationPending != true)
            {
                if (bigqueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    string url = bigqueue.Dequeue();
                    string urlHash = Hashing.HashString(url.ToLowerInvariant().Trim().ToString());
                    RAPI.ReceiveUrls(url, urlHash, cu, IsContentObject, ErrorCode);
                }                
            }
        }
```

So to reiterate the problems are:

1. Time outs on the send from the client to the service host.
2. The RunQueue() method does not run in the background.

> Any insights would be helpful, this is a very important program
>   designed to protect children from sexual exploitation and murder.

Comment: That is way too much code, Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 19 consecutive lines of commented out code should not be in a Stack Overflow post.

Comment: Changing the code may change the problem.

Comment: Not changing the code might lead to no answers.

Comment: And changing the code may help you discover the problem, that is why we ask you to do it. Take stuff out till it stops happening, then look at what you last took out.

Comment: lol - silly comments. Take stuff out until it stops happening? I could take all the code out and nothing happens at all! I will take the risk that there are no answers.

Comment: Acutally you are taking the risk of your question being closed. From the close reasons *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."*

Comment: Hey @Dave, nothing personal and nobody is picky, actually it's sort of rules, if you will. See the link in the very first comment.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain and you have the shortest code necessary to reproduce it as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's kind of impossible to remove code which is unnecessary when one does not know what is necessary for the problem to occur

Comment: Since you stated 2 problems, maybe you could split them into 2 questions?

Comment: It will make no difference to the code being shown splitting the questions into two... however, if that makes it easier for you, I will.

Comment: Well, not just for me, I think it will give you your answer faster. ;-)

Comment: Have you verified that you are stepping into the if (alOutUrls.Count > 100) statement?  Have you checked possible thread synchronization issues?  I don't see any mutual exclusion locking going on, but that doesn't mean there is an issue with that.

Comment: I don't see anywhere a code asking any task to run in background. I might as well run in the the same thread and then deadlock on the first `Thread.Sleep`. Starting a task doesn't ensure that a new thread will start, so using `Thread.Sleep` is strongly not recommended. Consider using [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and `Task.Delay`.

Comment: @Kryptos not sure how async/await works - shall look it up though - thanks.

Comment: @dustmouse yep that happens as expected.

Comment: @DaveGordon - Would the timeout be because the `while` loop in `RunQueue` on exits when `bgwCrawler.CancellationPending` is `true`? The loop just keeps going even though the queue has been emptied.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

RunQueue is supposed to be running in the background. But by calling Application.DoEvents() you are hijacking the UI processing. I don't know the exact effect of calling that from a background thread, but it can't be good.

Comment: That might be ONE of the problems indeed. But I'm not convinced this is the only one.

Comment: Neither am I, but you have to start somewhere.